# Sharepoint online app catalog creation not working (office 365 developer subscription)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, app, catalog

I have "Office 365 E3 Developer" license which contains "SharePoint Online for Developer" license.

When I go to app catalog creation in SharePoint admin in office 365 SharePoint admin center (classic one as new one does not contain app section) and then go to app catalog, create new, and fill out everything and then click OK.

I'm redirected back to app section of share point admin, but no site collection is created.

I tried this multiple times using edge and chrome.

Are there some changes that I missed so maybe I don't need app catalog anymore for SPFx development anymore?

If so - can you please post link to description of the changes, if not, what would be the best way to create app catalog?

Answer (score 0):

Just as I finally asked question on stackexchange i got apps site collection "creating" in site collection, it took about two hours for creation to even start.

Answer (score 0):

You will need anyone of the below subscription to create app catalog:

1. Office 365 Midsize Business
2. Office 365 Enterprise E1, E3, E4, or K1
3. Office 365 Education A2, A3, or A4
4. Office 365 Government G1, G3, G4, or K1

You can find the steps to create app catalog in Office 365 SharePoint tenant in below article: [Set up your Office 365 tenant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-developer-tenant).

Following all the steps, SharePoint creates the app catalog site, and you are able to see its progress in the SharePoint admin center(It may take sometime to reflect the changes).

> **Note**:
>   The following steps assume you are using the Classic SharePoint Admin Center. At this time, the modern SharePoint Admin Center does not have native support for creating an App Catalog. You can access the Classic SharePoint Admin Center from the left sidebar of the SharePoint Admin Center.

Comment: Hey... Does this answers your question?